# SVsBuildManagerAccessor fails when Publishing in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, publishing

Something is wrong with my VS 2010, i can't publish any project, i get an error:

Get service of SVsBuildManagerAccessor fails

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been trying to solve this for sometime.  Oddly, at the same time this started happening I started experiencing an issue with sql server management studio too.  The solution I found to this problem also resolved the issue with publishing using VS2010.

Just execute the following to re-register the ieproxy dll:

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

Hope this helps

Comment: Have you installed by any chance IE9 Beta?

Answer (score 1):

These problems might happen as a result of installing source gear vault version 3 or 4.
The solution to the problem is as Pat C answered.
You might also want to take a look at this thread for the SQL Server Problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d5d3e5fc-d8ce-4f42-b7ea-9bbbb7756a20/