# Visual Studio 2012 Crashes after installing IE9 (Faulting Module ntdll.dll)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Okay....

I've been running Visual Studio RTM since it's release on my work computer. Last Friday I installed/Updated IE to version 9 to test a JavaScript issue. After installing IE9 and rebooting my computer Visual Studio 2012 no longer works, it opens shows the start page for about a second then crashes.

I've unsuccessfully tried the following:

1. Revert to IE8 -- still crashes
2. Run devenv /SafeMode -- still crashes
3. Run devenv /ResetSettings -- still crashes
4. Repair VS2012 -- still crashes
5. Uninstall VS2012 completely and Reinstall -- still crashes
6. Uninstall VS2012 completely, removing all VS2012 folders and registry entries then reinstalling -- still crashes
7. (re)updating to IE9, uninstalling vs2012 and reinstalling -- still crashes

(countless rebooting after each meticulous step)

P.S. I cannot run System Restore since that is "disabled by your administrator" - that would have been before step # 4 above if it was available to me...

When I run devenv (safemode or not) I get the following in the Application Event Log:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011ecaa
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec49b8f
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00032582
Faulting process id: 0x1a6c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cda64fa375370b
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: e2a67638-1242-11e2-b5d0-78acc0b17d3e
```

Also... I have the output from devenv /log if it will be useful, but it's pretty much the same as what's in the App Event Log (pasted above)

I'm running Windows 7 Professional x64

Finally... I've found similar issues from google, but none of the causes match mine, nor do any of the fixes resolve my issue. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Previously found threads with similar issues:

1. [VS 2012 will not start](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/d848776a-b00f-4311-ab09-3a8777462968/)
2. [Visual Studio 2012 RC has stopped wokring](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vssetup/thread/223cf50b-bd7d-43ac-8b10-69c3dec72c1d)
3. [VS 2012 RTM Will Not Launch - Known Fixes Do Not Resolve](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/1e488859-b6f2-4133-88d7-a07190502879)

A few notes about these links:

1. I was not using VS2012 Commands extension.
2. I'm running Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RTM (not RC).
3. I do not have Microsoft ACT 5.6 Data Collector in my add/remove programs.

Comment: And before I get someone telling me to delete these registry keys... I already have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246224/visual-studio-2012-wont-start?rq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed the issue...

I noticed (when I went back to working in VS2010) that MSDeploy was no longer working. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034712/svsbuildmanageraccessor-fails-when-publishing-in-vs2010) i re-registered the ieproxy.dll and magically VS2012 seems to open and load my projects now!

I guess something in the upgrade from IE8 to IE9 messed up this registration and caused all sorts of trouble. Running the following at the command line fixed it.

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

Comment: Your comment just saved me from a world of pain. I'd buy you a beer. As it stand, enjoy some points. HELPFUL/A++ WOULD READ AGAIN

Comment: Same here. I got a similar problem after upgrading IE9 to IE10 and re-registering the proxy fixed it. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I started having this problem as soon as I updated to IE11, if you cannot start VS2012 after installing/upgrading IE definitely try this - it worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I removed a "security update" KB2750147 (after an other one, K278... can't remember) and now it's right.