# Visual Studio 2012 crash on startup

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events, crash

As soon as I open visual studio it goes unresponsive. I have looked at the event viewer, and it gives 3 errors when visual studio crashes in order:

1)

```
Application: WDExpress.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

2)

```
Faulting application name: WDExpress.exe, version: 11.0.60315.1, time stamp: 0x5142b273
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b83c8a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x18f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce445978318661
Faulting application path: D:\Programs\vs\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: bbf0314d-b04c-11e2-a8b8-08002700c410
```

3)

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: wdexpress.exe
P2: 11.0.60315.1
P3: 5142b273
P4: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0
P5: 11.0.60315.1
P6: 514298c6
P7: 941
P8: 5b
P9: System.InvalidOperationException
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Temp\WER2FF6.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_wdexpress.exe_b14ec39a92949f27abbb79e507ed518f9c5afcf_0abe3755

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: bbf0314d-b04c-11e2-a8b8-08002700c410
```

I have reinstalled at least 8 times, uninstalled using the default uninstaller. Then used revo uninstaller, manually cleaned registry keys, run .net verifier (no errors), repaired the install, tried on another account.  It simply will not work. Any ideas?

P.S this is my last resort I've been looking everywhere and am unable to solve it even when others have similar problems

Comment: i dont follow what do u mean

Comment: It is about a developer tool so on topic here

Answer (score 0):

I've been annoyed by the symptom which seems to be exactly the same. 
In my case, regsvr ieproxy.dll made the symptom fixed.

Hope this helps:
[Visual Studio 2012 Crashes after installing IE9 (Faulting Module ntdll.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806979/visual-studio-2012-crashes-after-installing-ie9-faulting-module-ntdll-dll)